# Running java application parallely on multicore cluster nodes

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a Java program that calculates semantic similarity between two documents. The program retrieves documents from a specified file system and calculates similarity. There are around 2,00,000 such docs.
I have created 10 threads for this task and I have assigned data chucks to each of the thread. For ex. documents 1-20000 for the first thread and 20001-40000 to the next thread and so on.
Currently I am running the above program in a 8 CPU-core machine. Its taking a lot of time to finish the calculations.
I want to run the program on a 5 node Linux cluster where each node has 64 cores.

- Are there any frameworks available in Java like EXECUTOR Framework which can do this task?
- Is There a way on how to calculate the maximum number of threads that one can spawn?

  Any pointers on how to resolve this or do it better would be appreciated.

Comment: do you compare each of 200000 documents to one predefined document or to all other documents?

Comment: You asked same question which I am looking, +1 for such nice question (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Are there any frameworks available in Java like EXECUTOR Framework which can do this task?**

I suggest you to take a look at the [Akka framework](http://akka.io/) for writing powerful concurrent & distributed applications. Akka uses the Actor Model together with Software Transactional Memory to raise the abstraction level and provide a better platform to build correct concurrent and scalable applications.

Take a look at the step by step [tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-java.html) that gives more information about how to build a distributed application using Akka framework.

In general, distributed applications are built in Java using [Java-RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html) that internally uses Java's inbuilt serialization to pass the objects between the nodes.

**Is There a way on how to calculate the maximum number of threads that one can spawn?**

The simple rule that we use is, **set to higher value than the available logical cores in the system**. How much higher value depends on the type of operations that we do. For example, if the computation involves IO communication then set the number of threads to 2 * available logical cores (Not the physical cores).

Other ideas that we use,

- Measure the CPU utilization by increasing the number of threads one by one and stop when the CPU utilization reaches close to 90-100%
- Measure the throughput and stop the point at which throughput stays or starts to degrade

Answer (score 0):

Java's [Fork/Join framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)  is your friend. As the opening statement of this framework says:

> The fork/join framework is an implementation of the ExecutorService
>   interface that helps you take **advantage of multiple processors**. It is
>   designed for work that can be broken into smaller pieces recursively.
>   The goal is to use all the available processing power to enhance the
>   performance of your application.

*On how many threads you can spawn* - I think there is no such hard and fast rule, it depends. So can try to start with a number like 5 or so, and then keep on increasing or decreasing based on result.
Also, you can analyze your existing maximum and minimum number of threads, and contrast it with CPU utilization etc., and proceed like this to understand how your system is behaving. If your application is deployed in application server, then check its threading model and what they say about thread capacity.